# regex - how to look for a set of items whose order in the line is irrelevant

Tags: regex, pcre

Let's say I'm looking for a line of text that has a set of items `a`, `b`, and `c` and the order in which they appear may be different when they do appear.

Using Perl-compatible regular expressions, is there a "function" that can give you a regex to detect lines where `a`, `b`, and `c` appear somewhere in the line **with the order being irrelevant**?

Without such a function, you would have `N!` expressions that you'd have to OR, `N` is number of unique items.

```
regex = (.*a.*b.*c.*)|(.*a.*c.*b.*)|(.*b.*c.*a.*)|(.*b.*a.*c.*)|(.*c.*a.*b.*)|(.*c.*b.*a.*)
```

I'd settle for an online tool that can generate regular expressions.

Note: this question is meant to be language agnostic i.e. one-liner regex expressions. 
However, it may necessary to use a language like Python or Perl if the needed functionality is not native to Perl-compatible regular expressions.

**UPDATE 1**

Issue brought up: what if `a`, `b`, `c` overlap as in `mess`, `sag`, `message`?

Should the regex be constructed so that overlapped words fail or succeed in the search?

Comment: What about using lookaheads: `(?=.*?a)(?=.*?b)(?=.*?c)`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen what is the `/` at end and beginning?

Comment: @revo I was wrong you can have `*` in lookahead.

Comment: All regex flavors support variable-length lookaheads.

Comment: Are items allowed to overlap? e.g. if a is "mess," b is "sag," and c is "age" should "message" match or fail?

Comment: @revo is there a way to deal with overlapping using built-in regex functionality?

Comment: @MichaelCarman using lookahead it will definitely overlap because lookahead doesn't consume characters.

Comment: @Adrian: I know what look-ahead will do, I'm asking whether or not that behavior is acceptable.

Comment: With my dataset, I won't have that problem. But for this question to be useful to more people, I'll leave question open (and add info).

Comment: In the case of overlapping, @sln's answer provides a neat workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need that unnecessary pipes as you are simply able to benefit from lookaheads:

```
(?=.*?a)(?=.*?b)(?=.*?c)
```

Comment: Works. Why do you need to put `?` after the `.*`

Comment: Making our quantifier lazy will avoid taking extra steps to look for a pattern. Laziness stops at the very first occurrence but greediness iterates  over every character then does backtrack. @Adrian

Comment: Can you provide a link that states this? I use [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround2.html) as my goto for regex.

Comment: You may study around [lazy and greedy quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). @Adrian

Comment: Whether a greedy or a non-greedy quantifier is more efficient depends only on whether the following pattern is to be found nearer the beginning or end of the string. Since you have no information on this at all, you should avoid the extra noise and use ordinary greedy quantifiers.

Comment: *"Making our quantifier lazy will avoid taking extra steps to look for a pattern"* **This is untrue**

Comment: Although I completely do agree with it as a *fact*, it's all about possibilities and our match being there within first-half of the input string is more likely to happen or first-half of the input string is more interesting to be counted on (*is prefered more than the second-half*) like a binary search does normally take steps. So possibly you may not call it *untrue*. @Borodin

Comment: And if you find my statement *untrue* then yours seems the same, even much more: *you should avoid the extra noise and use ordinary greedy quantifiers.* @Borodin

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to cram everything into a single regex pattern. You're using Perl, so use Perl!

```
/a/ and /b/ and /c/
```

will do exactly as you ask

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I'm not actually using Perl. I put that tag because stackoverflow popup suggested it. I'll remove.

Comment: @Adrian: Okay, well I'm sure that whatever language you're using has a logical `&&` operator!

Comment: It's a mix of Python and notepad++.

Comment: @Adrian: Okay. So you can combine regex tests with an `&&`

Comment: in notepad++? I'll try it later

Comment: Not in Notepad++. In Python

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-Order parsing with pcre/perl regex.
No need for permutations.

`(?:.*?(?:(?(1)(?!))(a)|(?(2)(?!))(b)|(?(3)(?!))(c))){3}`

Expanded

```
 (?:
      .*? 
      (?:
           (?(1)
                (?!)
           )
           ( a )                         # (1)
        |  
           (?(2)
                (?!)
           )
           ( b )                         # (2)
        |  
           (?(3)
                (?!)
           )
           ( c )                         # (3)
      )
 ){3}
```

Just add as many as you need.
If you require say 5 out of 10, just change the range quantifier
at the outer scope to `{5,10}`.

Comment: It flags the capture group the first time it matches. Here, we don't let it match again because we want _distinct_ alternations to match the selected _range_ amount of times. In this case we are matching 3 out of 3 unique alternation items. The out of order means capture group 3 could match before 1.. There are many variations to this that gets into some real power, like some of the alternation constructs are unknown and _not_ unique.